# scipy.curve_fit() does not work for an exponential

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have four points: sigma2 = [15, 8, 5.5, 3.21], obtained for points [100, 300, 500, 1000]. I want to fit an exponential curve to this, and then measure the value for 800.

However, when I try to do so, I simply get a horizontal line.

Here is my code:

```
sigma2 = [15, 8, 5.5, 3.21]

def exp_fit(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

x_data = np.asarray([100, 300, 500, 1000], dtype=np.float64)
y_data = np.asarray(sigma2, dtype=np.float64)

param_exp, _ = curve_fit(exp_fit, x_data, y_data)

x_test = np.arange(100, 1100, 100)
print(exp_fit(x_test, *param_exp))
plt.plot(x_test, exp_fit(x_test, *param_exp), 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(param_exp))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I realize it is a simple thing, but I can't quite put my finger on the error I am making.

I did try to negate the initial value of x as suggested in other posts, but it still does not work.
I tried to bound the exponential as follows:

```
    param_exp, _ = curve_fit(exp_fit, x_data, y_data, bounds=(0, [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]))
```

and now I see a straight line with a negative slope.

Comment: Bounding is necessary but insufficient. You also need to pass in a sane initial guess for your parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Reinderien, that was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SciPy's curve fitting methods rely on gradient information - in other words, if adjusting a parameter doesn't seem to do anything, they won't use it. For that reason, it's important to provide good initial guesses for the optimizers.

The default guess provided for b here is 1, which results in the exponential term being near-zero.

```py
>>> b = 1
>>> np.exp(-b * x_data)
array([3.72007598e-044, 5.14820022e-131, 7.12457641e-218, 0.00000000e+000])
```

The following initial guess seems to work well:

```py
c0 = a0 = 1
b0 = np.log(np.mean(y_data)) / np.mean(x_data)
p0 = a0, b0, c0
param_exp, _ = curve_fit(exp_fit, x_data, y_data, p0=p0)
```

Comment: Perfect! Is this mentioned in the docs? I must have missed it.

Comment: @Belleroph0N I'm not aware of anywhere in the docs where this is mentioned (anyone who does know, feel free to chime in) but in general, SciPy has local optimization solvers and global optimization solvers. The local optimization solvers can get trapped in local minima (or places where the gradient is flat, or places where the gradient is too steep.) The [global optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization) solvers are smart enough to get out of local minima, at the cost of greatly increased search time.